# Prevent versioning for .woff (font) files

Tags: query, fonts

I'm trying to pass the preload check of Google PSI, so i've placed the local fonts i got, in the `<head>` as suggested using preload, as:

```
<link rel="preload" as="font" href="myfont.woff" type="font/woff2" crossorigin>
<link rel="preload" as="font" href="myfont.woff" type="font/woff2" crossorigin>
<link rel="preload" as="font" href="myfont2.woff" type="font/woff2" crossorigin>
```

problem is, something is versioning it, so PSI still report it as not preloaded showing me the url of the font is something like `myfont.woff?18238125` , how can avoid versioning it, or strip the query at the end via php?

Answer (score 0):

If you load your fonts using standard stylesheet enqueueing then you can add this to your functions.php file:

```
function remove_querystrings( $src ) {
    $parts = explode( '.woff?ver', $src );
    return $parts[0];
}
add_filter( 'style_loader_src',  'remove_querystrings', 15, 1 );
```

I haven't tested this but I'm fairly certain it will only work if you're adding the fonts with `wp_enqueue_style();`.

I use the above in production environments to remove the query string from all scripts and styles not just fonts, but that's only on finalized sites where the only updates are to content.  *(On that note, I've never tested it with `.woff` in front of the `?ver`.)*

Comment: Careful cause this code breaks functions.php . Thanks for your reply above, I found something like that before, but I realised the problem was really stupid, basically the version was a static version wrote inside the css, due to the fact it is a icons font i created with a tool online that versions it as it seems, so i simply deleted it from the css

Comment: Which one breaks functions.php?  The answer or the snippet in comments.  I haven’t had a chance to test either.

Comment: The snippet in the comments

Comment: Thanks Robert, deleting it now so no one accidentally tries to apply it.